# Error estimates in the $L^2$ norm of conforming FEM about Poisson’s equation with mixed boundary conditions

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, numerical-analysis-of-pde, finite-element-method

Consider Poisson’s equation

$$- \Delta u = f{\rm\qquad{     in  }}\;\Omega $$

with following mixed boundary cconditions

$$u = g{\rm\qquad{ on }}\;\Gamma  \subset \partial \Omega $$ 
$$\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial n}} = h{\qquad\rm{        on  }}\;\partial \Omega \backslash \Gamma$$

where $\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial n}}$ denotes the derivative of $u$ in the direction normal to the boundary, $\partial \Omega$. When $g=0$ and $h=0$, the problem becomes homogeneous boundary condition.

I already know the *Aubin-Nitsche* trick to get error estimates for $u - {u_h}$ in the $L^2$ norm with homogeneous boundary condition. I learned the duality argument from Brenner and Scott's book *[The mathematical theory of finite element methods](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-0-387-75934-0)*. But when the boundary condition is inhomogeneous, it is difficult for me to get error estimates for $u - {u_h}$ in the $L^2$ norm using duality argument. Although the book says,

> ...inhomogeneous boundary conditions are easily treated' and the proof is analogous

I encountered a problem arising from the Neumann boundary condition. When the boundary condition is homogeneous, I can get the dual problem

$$a\left( {v,w} \right) = \left( {u - {u_h},v} \right)\qquad\forall v \in H_0^1\left( \Omega  \right)$$

and the elliptic regularity estimates

$${\left| w \right|_{{H^2}}} \le C{\left\| {u - {u_h}} \right\|_{{L^2}}}$$

which is crucial to the proof. In the case of inhomogeneous boundary condition, however, I get the dual problem

$$a\left( {v,w} \right) = \left( {r - {r_h},v} \right) + {\left( {h,v} \right)_{\partial \Omega \backslash \Gamma }}\qquad\forall v \in H_0^1\left( \Omega  \right)$$

and the elliptic regularity estimates

$${\left| w \right|_{{H^2}}} \le C\left( {{{\left\| {r - {r_h}} \right\|}_{{L^2}}} + {{\left\| h \right\|}_{{H^{\frac{1}{2}}}}}} \right)$$

which $r = u - \tilde u$, $\tilde u \in {H^1}\left( \Omega\right)$ and ${\left.{\tilde u} \right|_\Gamma } = g$. In the following steps of proof, I try to estimate ${\left( {h,v} \right)_{\partial \Omega \backslash \Gamma }}$ and ${{{\left\| h \right\|}_{{H^{\frac{1}{2}}}}}}$, but I didn't get the result.

**Questions:**

1. Is my idea about the proof of the inhomogeneous boundary condition, such as the dual problem and the elliptic regularity estimate which I get, correct?
2. If my idea about the proof is correct, how can I continue to prove the error estimates for $u - {u_h}$ in the $L^2$ norm(my idea to estimate ${\left( {h,v} \right)_{\partial \Omega \backslash \Gamma }}$ and ${{{\left\| h \right\|}_{{H^{\frac{1}{2}}}}}}$)?
3. If my idea about the proof is wrong, how to obtain the error estimates for $u - {u_h}$ in the $L^2$ norm(the case of inhomogeneous boundary condition)?Please tell me the proof or the main idea of the proof.
4. I already know that the proof of error estimates about model problems which are homogeneous boundary conditions. Who can tell me some references about the proof of the $H^1$ and $L^2$ norm error estimates with inhomogeneous boundary conditions?

Note:Many thanks for Anton Menshov's reedit.